# Is there a more elegant, or at least more DRY, way to write this series of SQL IFs?

Tags: mysql

The title explains my whole question. Here's the query:

```
select
date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(date_of_birth, '%Y') age,
IF(date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(date_of_birth, '%Y') < 18,
  'Under 18',
  IF(date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(date_of_birth, '%Y') <= 24,
    '19 to 24',
    IF(date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(date_of_birth, '%Y') <= 34,
      '25 to 34',
      'Over 34'))) age_range
from customer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a combination of case and a nested query - something like:

```
select s.age,
       case when s.age < 18 then 'Under 18'
            when s.age <= 24 then '19 to 24'
            when s.age <= 34 then '25 to 34'
            else 'Over 34'
       end case as age_range
from (select date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(date_of_birth, '%Y') as age
      from customer) s
```

Comment: I'm selecting this as the answer because it seems to be the closest thing to working code (all you're missing is an alias for your subquery). I'm disappointed that a subquery would be necessary because I need this query to be as fast as possible, but I suppose I could replace the subquery with a view and probably be okay. (And, of course, I didn't say anything about performance in my question, so I'm not trying to disparage your answer in that way.)

Comment: The only reason for the sub-query was so that the age calculation only needed to be included once - if the sub-query slows things down too much, I suggest replacing `age` in the case clause with `date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(date_of_birth, '%Y')` and moving `from customer` out of the sub-query. (Of course, that would be somewhat less elegant...)

Comment: Right. Either I have to replace `age` with `date_format...` (not DRY) or create a view (which will almost certainly hinder performance). I think I'll try creating a view first, since `age` will probably be useful in other contexts in addition to this one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good match for [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html).

Is should look something like the following (untested):

```
select
date_format(now(), '%Y') - date_format(date_of_birth, '%Y') age, 
        CASE age 
          WHEN age < 18 THEN 'Under 18'
          WHEN age <= 24 THEN '19 - 24'
          WHEN age <= 34 THEN '25 - 34'
          ELSE 'Over 34'
        END CASE AS age_range
from customer
```